Construct a new tuple type from existing tuples
I have a list structure as a flattened input to a API
(point_x, point_y, thing_a, thing_b, thing_c)

This real structure is a very long list of a many flattened objects. This example is a much simplified case.
I would like to make the types that create it clear in python
from typing import Tuple

point = (int, int)
thing = (int, float, str)
TypeA = Tuple[point + thing]

This is a valid python type:
typing.Tuple[int, int, int, float, str]

However, MyPy does not like it
.
Invalid type alias: expression is not a valid type [valid-type]

The real structure I have is very complex and it's helpful for devs to see how the structure is created.
How can I do this properly without MyPy causing errors

Just as an addendum, the following is not a valid solution
from typing import Tuple
Tuple[
    int,     # point_x
    int,     # point_y
    int,     # thing_a
    float,   # thing_b
    str      # thing_c
]


Any particular reason you want this type to be a plain tuple? Apparently your API takes a list anyway, so you don't have to use a tuple simply to fulfill API requirements. Why not use a dataclass, or a namedtuple, or just write your own class?

Edited to make it clear that the API takes a tuple. List and Tuples are interchangeable anyway but the point is to clearly label the types of each constituent. I'm wondering if this is a bug in MyPy related to https://github.com/python/mypy/pull/7409

Note that Tuple[int, int, int, float, str] is not the same as Tuple[point + thing]. The latter is equivalent to Tuple[(int, int, int, float, str)], if anything.

@deceze - I don't think that's correct as they even point to the same memory location Tuple[int, int, int, float, str] is Tuple[point + thing] and id(Tuple[int, int, int, float, str]), id(Tuple[point + thing]). I think your comment is possibly how MyPy interprets it but the compiler takes a different view? Maybe this is part of then problem ?

Interesting, I stand corrected. Didn't know Tuple accepts a sequence in addition to separate values. If anything, MyPy mightn't do the runtime evaluation necessary to construct this then.

mypy is a static analyzer. It doesn't care if executing Tuple[point + thing] would work fine at runtime; it cares about the fact that point + thing is an attempt to dynamically compute type arguments, which it considers invalid.

Is this linked to the documentation which states you cannot conditionally create types? I don't think it is just the + that causes the problem. Consider the example of Tuple[point] and it still throws an error? This time albeit "point is not valid as a type", linking to the docs: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#variables-vs-type-aliases

You need to define "type-level tuples", using tuple[...], not (...).
point = tuple[int, int]
thing = tuple[int, float, str]

You can unpack them to define TypeA:
TypeA = tuple[*point, *thing]

which can then be used as a type hint:
x: TypeA = (1, 2, 3, 4.5, "foo")  # OK
y: TypeA = ("bar", 2, 3, 4.5, "foo")  # Error


Huh. I knew about the new TypeVarTuple thing, but I didn't know you could unpack actual tuple types now. Apparently this is indeed accepted by mypy now, though.

This does look nice! What version of python is this supported from ? I'm on python 3.8 right now and getting an error ! Do you have any workaround for 3.8?

@AlexanderMcFarlane yes, just quote the whole right-hand side of these assignments.
